# A definition of having small hom-sets by Wood

Tags: category-theory

In the paper entitled "Some Remarks on Total Categories" by Wood the author says that a category $\mathfrak{B}$ has small hom-sets if it has a hom-functor $(\cdot,\cdot): \mathfrak{B}^{op} \times \mathfrak{B} \longrightarrow {\bf Set}$. Such a definition is not clear to me.

Such a hypothesis seems to be related to the fact that $Hom_\mathfrak{B}(A,B)$ is a set for each $A,B \in \mathfrak{B}$, which is always assumed when defining a category is given (see Borceux or Awodey for instance). Which is the real difference between Wood's definition and the fact that $Hom_\mathfrak{B}(A,B)$ is a set for each $A,B \in \mathfrak{B}$? Are there categories (in the usual sense) which have not small hom-sets, according to Wood's terminology?

Comment: Large categories are defined to have hom-*classes*. The locally small categories are those with hom-*sets*. It is a common convention to have "category" mean "large category".

Comment: So, he means that $\mathfrak{B}$ has small hom-sets if and only if it is "locally small"?

Comment: Yes, it's a little tautological.